# How are RAID device names detected at boot on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, software-raid

When I boot my ubuntu 10.04 server It only partially detects the drives as an inactive raid array with a funny name "md_d1". I have to stop and remove this 'device' every time and then add the new drives like this:

```
arthur@macro:~/Desktop$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md_d1 : inactive sdd[3](S)
      732574448 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>
arthur@macro:~/Desktop$ sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md_d1
mdadm: stopped /dev/md_d1
arthur@macro:~/Desktop$ sudo mdadm --remove /dev/md_d1
arthur@macro:~/Desktop$ sudo mdadm --incremental /dev/sdd
mdadm: /dev/sdd attached to /dev/md/d1, not enough to start (1).
arthur@macro:~/Desktop$ sudo mdadm --incremental /dev/sdb
mdadm: /dev/sdb attached to /dev/md/d1, not enough to start safely.
arthur@macro:~/Desktop$ sudo mdadm --incremental /dev/sdc
mdadm: /dev/sdc attached to /dev/md/d1, which has been started.
```

Im currious where this name comes from and how RAID arrays are detected at boot. Why is this happening (and it would be nice to fix it)

Answer (score 1):

Usually the init scripts read `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` for ARRAY definitions; failing that they do something "sensible" like scanning all disks/partitions for superblocks. The [man page for mdadm](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mdadm) suggests:

> ```
> echo ’DEVICE /dev/hd[a-z] /dev/sd*[a-z]’ > mdadm.conf
> mdadm --examine --scan --config=mdadm.conf >> mdadm.conf
> ```
>
> This  will find arrays which could be assembled from existing IDE and SCSI whole drives (not partitions), and store the information in the format of a config file.  This file is very likely to contain unwanted detail, particularly the devices=  entries.   It  should  be  reviewed  and edited before being used as an actual config file.

as a starting point for a decent config. The [manpage for mdadm.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/mdadm.conf) gives some examples:

```
DEVICE /dev/sd[bcdjkl]1
DEVICE /dev/hda1 /dev/hdb1

# /dev/md0 is known by its UID.
ARRAY /dev/md0 UUID=3aaa0122:29827cfa:5331ad66:ca767371
# /dev/md1 contains all devices with a minor number of
#   1 in the superblock.
ARRAY /dev/md1 superminor=1
# /dev/md2 is made from precisely these two devices
ARRAY /dev/md2 devices=/dev/hda1,/dev/hdb1
```

The names you're seeing are the defaults:

> The standard names for non-partitioned arrays (the only sort of md array available in 2.4 and earlier) are either of
>
> ```
>           /dev/mdNN
>           /dev/md/NN
> ```
>
> where NN is a number.  The standard names for partitionable arrays (as available from 2.6 onwards) are either of
>
> ```
>           /dev/md/dNN
>           /dev/md_dNN
> ```

Comment: I'm not qualified to comment or grade this answer but it would be helpful if someone would clarify as it seems spot on to me.